# MDADM RAID expand underlying partitions but has subpartitions

Tags: centos6, software-raid, mdadm

I have a box that I configured to use MD RAID during the install process for the OS and boot drive. It's this weird `/dev/md0p#` structure that confuses me.

The installer produced `/dev/md0p1` (`/boot`), `/dev/md0p2` (`/var/lib/mysql`), `/dev/md0p3` (`/`), `/dev/md0p4` (`extended`), `/dev/md0p5` (`swap`). I noticed it did this for all physically installed machines from the CentOS 6 DVD.

How do I increase the size of the `/dev/md0p3`? I need this root partition to be expanded. I feel like I need to delete the `/dev/md0p3`, `/dev/md0p4`, `/dev/md0p5` partitions and then create a new one for `/dev/md0p3` with the extra space. I don't care for p4 and p5, because they don't contain actual data. I can create them after the fact.

I am confused on the order of deleting partitions and adding the space in respect to `/dev/md0`. `fdisk -l` shows the drives `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` and then finally `/dev/md0` with all of the sub partitions.

Comment: used gparted Live CD. did the modifications of delete and expand like I mentioned. worked out.